# Stretch image to fit full container width bootstrap

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image that's 1300px wide, using bootstrap I want this image to fill the full width of my container which is set to 1300px. I create a row, give it a full 12 columns and then add in the image with a class of image responsive. With this set up I get the output below.

[image]

I want my image to stretch all the way along to where my image is in my content, here is my code.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/homeBanner.jpg" alt="placeholder 960" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The image is set to width 100% so not sure why it isn't filling the container.

Comment: `row` class must be nested of `container` class, change the order to `.container > .row > .col`

Comment: that made my image go even smaller

Comment: pocockn only if you agree it is superior, you could consider accepting @Poikilos's answer for the benefit of future visitors to this page

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In bootstrap 4.1, the w-100 class is required along with img-fluid for images smaller than the page to be stretched:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <img class='img-fluid w-100' src="#" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

see closed issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20830

(As of 2018-04-20, the documentation is wrong: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/ says that img-fluid applies max-width: 100%; height: auto;" but img-fluid does not resolve the issue, and neither does manually adding those style attributes with or without bootstrap classes on the img tag.)

Comment: Surely this is correct answer, if you were to follow bootstraps simple grid rules instead of hacking it with overrides.

Comment: This is the most Bootstrappy answer imho. But one issue is that it causes scrollbars.

Comment: What about the other way around? When the image is too big and is getting out of the screen...

Answer (score 43):

Check if this solves the problem:

```
<div class="container-fluid no-padding">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=1300%C3%97400&w=1300&h=400" alt="placeholder 960" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.no-padding {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Css class `no-padding` will override default bootstrap container padding.

Full example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/67nmbg1L/).

---

**@Update**
If you use bootstrap 4 it could be done even simpler

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=1300%C3%97400&w=1300&h=400" alt="placeholder 960" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Updated example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/67nmbg1L/).

Comment: In Bootstrap 4 you can use the class `px-0` which stands for `padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;`. [Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/)

Comment: Actually the most appropriate would be `class="container-fluid p-0"`

Comment: in `bootstrap4` use `img-fluid` instead of `img-responsive`

Answer (score 12):

First of all if the size of the image is smaller than the container, then only "img-fluid" class will not solve your problem. you have to set the width of image to 100%, for that you can use Bootstrap class "w-100".
keep in mind that "container-fluid" and "col-12" class sets left and right padding to 15px and "row" class sets left and right margin to "-15px" by default.
 make sure to set them to 0.

**Note:**
"px-0" is a bootstrap class which sets left and right padding to 0 and
"mx-0" is a bootstrap class which sets left and right margin to 0

P.S. i am using Bootstrap 4.0 version.

```
 <div class="container-fluid px-0">
        <div class="row mx-0">
            <div class="col-12 px-0">
            <img src="images/top.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me. *Note: Adding the image within a row introduces some space so I've intentionally used only a div to encapsulate the image.*

```
<div class="container-fluid w-100 h-auto m-0 p-0">  

    <img src="someimg.jpg" class="img-fluid w-100 h-auto p-0 m-0" alt="Patience">           

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`container` class has 15px left & right padding, so if you want to remove this padding, use following, because `row` class has -15px left & right margin.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <img class='img-responsive' src="#" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/m-dehghani/pen/jqeKgv

Comment: I would avoid hacking the normal flow of classes in Bootstrap (always insert a `.col` inside a `.row`) . Removing the padding from either the container or the columns seems like a better approach. Another option would be to completely remove all of the bootstrap classes (`.container`, `.row` and `.col`) and then open a `.container` on the next section.

Comment: Removing the padding using css just add some unnecessary code and overload to the page, there is no benefit overwriting padding over my solution, if there is any, please let me know. (_there is nothing wrong with using `.row` without `.col`, if your designer want to, using `.col` without `.row` is wrong tho, because of `float`_) also removing `.container`  is not possible, because you add `.container` class because you want to design boxed-view. without `.container` there is no limit on `width`, _unless you define your container, e.g: my-container, which is wrong and unnecessary_.

Comment: I didn't suggest to insert a `.col` without a `.row`, in fact what I meant was to stick to the `.container` > `.row` > `.col` structure as much as you can. If you feel confident in not inserting a `.col` inside a `.row` of course you can do it and maybe you won't have any problem, but in my experience it's better to avoid it in order to be able to change the structure in the future if you need to.

Comment: I know you didn't suggest to insert a `.col` without a `.row`, I added that info for making my comment more useful (hopefully). and yes, your solution works too, actually the accepted answer is similar to your solution, about flexibility, it depends, editing css over editing html (_in order to change the structure, as you mentioned_) is not always easier, I think the only advantage of my solution over yours is less html tag and css, that's all

Answer (score -2):

This will do the same as many of the other answers, but will make sides flush with the window, so there is no scroll bars.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="padding: 0;">
       <img src="example.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Example">  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```